# Wordpress update_option returning false

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a perplexing problem with the Wordpress update_option function

This line is returning false.

```
var_dump(update_option('category_light_box_'.$tag, $lightbox_pid));
```

Where `$tag` and `$lightbox_pid` are validated numbers.

The function this line is part of is called with the `edit_category` hook / filter.

I have tried running a repair statement on the wp_options table and restarted the server, to no effect.
Is there anyway for me to view the sql being used? Can anyone suggest a debugging method?

Edit:
The full function code:

```
public static function save_categories ($tag) {
        echo 'save';

        if (preg_match('/^[0-9]{1,}$/', $_POST['category-lightbox']) && $_POST['category-lightbox'] !== '0') {
            $lightbox_pid = $_POST['category-lightbox'];

            var_dump(update_option('category_light_box_'.$tag, $lightbox_pid));
        } 
    }
```

and the action call:

```
add_action( 'edit_category', array ('ib_lightbox_application', 'save_categories'));
```

Edit:

I've added `define('SAVEQUERIES', true);` in my config file and var_dumped the `$wpdb->queries` array after calling wp_update. The sql statement that the update should generate is not present so it looks like update_option is failing on validation somehow.

Comment: are you sure $lightbox_pid is not empty?

Comment: `update_option()` returns `false` if the update fails OR if it doesn't change. Did you check the old value?

Comment: $lightbox_pid is populated (for testing purposes I am setting it to '30') when echoed immediately before the problem line. There are no options starting with category_light_box_ at all

Answer (score 3):

OK I discovered by trial and error that there is an undocumented requirement for the first argument of update_options to contain no numbers, (I have no idea why). $tag is always a number.

I rewrote my function as follows to remove the need for unique options per category:

```
public static function save_categories ($tag) {

        if (preg_match('/^[0-9]{1,}$/', $_POST['category-lightbox']) && $_POST['category-lightbox'] !== '0') {
            $lightbox_pid = $_POST['category-lightbox'];

            $lightboxes = get_option('category_light_box', '');
            $lightboxes = json_decode($lightboxes, true);
            $lightboxes[$tag] = $lightbox_pid;
            $lightboxes = json_encode($lightboxes);

            update_option('category_light_box', $lightboxes);
        } 
    }
```

Comment: You made my day :)
I was looking for a solution for a long time, till I came across your great solution. Why they don't allow number anyway?

Comment: Better question is, why it is not documented? Seems like pretty important requirement to me since there are no specialized exceptions and all you get is generic `false` in return when `update_option()` fails